# Vocal chords or cords?

Tags: word-choice, orthography

Which one is correct, and don't tell me vocal folds.

When you talk about someone singing, are they using their vocal cords or their vocal chords?

I found [this](http://blog.oup.com/2007/10/corpus-2/) which thankfully shed some light on the topic for me.

Comment: http://choirly.com/vocal-folds-vocal-chords-or-vocal-cords/

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Unless you're addressing [polyphonic overtone singing](http://sploid.gizmodo.com/watching-this-woman-singing-two-notes-at-the-same-time-1642829131), people sing *notes*, not *chords*. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. A list of these references can be found here: [List of general references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/). Please take a few minutes to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: I saw that choirly link when I googled, but it has a typo in the first sentence, which made me suspect it was garbage.

Comment: Also, this: http://blog.oup.com/2007/10/corpus-2/ "So we find contemporary writers opting for vocal chords instead of vocal cords 49% of the time" - See more at: http://blog.oup.com/2007/10/corpus-2/#sthash.zkVqoE9U.dpuf

Comment: @medica, ArmenԾիրունյան in case you didn't see jgritty's comments above I think you should. More importantly OED gives both *chord* and *cord*. Johnson remarked in the first entry in the OED 'cord' is the preferred modern spelling of chord, but when the primitive meaning is required the 'h' remains. The modern entry says that for mathematical chord and emotional chord the 'h' is the only possible spelling. For the physiological usages 'vocal, spinal, spermatic, umbilical chord', usage varies between *chord* and *cord*. The question needs reopening, and comments deleting. They're misleading ;)

Comment: @Josh61 Please see comment above this one. If you have access to the OED online, please see [here](http://www.oed.com.ezproxy.is.ed.ac.uk/view/Entry/32295?result=1&rskey=sIOej6&)

Comment: +1 for an interesting and obviously well-motivated question, which would be enlightening for readers. Nice article link too! :)

Comment: @medica, ArmenԾիրունյան Here's a page from [Carnegie Mellon University](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/24-ansys/htm_tests/t_v1_vocal.htm), and here's [18, 400 examples of *vocal chords* from academic journals](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=+%22vocal+chords%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=). In his famous work on English, the world renowned scholar Otto Jespersen used "chords" not "cords"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to a person's voice/singing it would be "vocal cords". "Chord" is basically a harmonic set of three/more notes and it's more music based than human based.

Comment: Wouldn't you class this as general reference?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please see my comment above from OED. Anything but general reference really, given the other comments here!

Comment: chord (kɔːd)
n ...

3. (Anatomy) anatomy a variant spelling of cord
...
Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OK, but an online reference? (i.e. commonly available). American dictionaries don't seem to give it. The only answer here is substantially and materially wrong. The comment underneath it suggests that the wrong answer can be found via general reference. At least one of the close-voters wrote a materially and substantially misleading comment below the question, thereby giving some authority to their factually incorrect comment ... (thankfully now deleted). There are a couple of other comments that are factually incorrect and a link to a dud website giving duff information ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth ... as it stands this closure is doing a bit of a, hmm,  disservice to the site, imo - by misleading readers ;)

Comment: @Araucaria Shouldn't you be addressing the close-voters? I hadn't fully decided. But both AHDEL (an American dictionary certainly giving the sense) and Collins are easily available [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chord). So now I am fully decided. General reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wa trying to pull you in a reopen vote direction...  It is in the AHDEL as you say: *3. Anatomy Variant of cord.* But note that, doesn't necessarily apply to every anatomical compound word with 'cord in'. So a reader wouldn't know for sure ... Anyway, I give up, I haven't persuaded anyone, so maybe there's something I'm just not seeing ...

Comment: I think you're missing that Collins gives two homographs: **chord** (kɔːd)
n
1. (Mathematics) maths
a....
3. (Anatomy) anatomy a variant spelling of cord
4. ...
[C16: from Latin chorda, from Greek khordē gut, string; see cord]
ˈchorded adj **/////**
chord (kɔːd)
n
1. (Music, other) the simultaneous sounding of a group of musical notes, usually three or more in number. See concord4, discord3
vb
2.  ...
Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003